# Column in having clause does not exist issue in Doctrine and pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm, pgadmin

I am running a query in pgadmin but facing issue column distance does not exist

```
select f.title, f.longitude, f.latitude, (3959 * cos(cos(radians('52.512452')) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians('13.390931')) + sin(radians('52.512452')) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance from fitness_studio f having distance<1 order by distance desc
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,

Aisha

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know postgresql has no way to directly use an alias column in where clause. So you should either try to duplicate the logic:

```
SELECT
  f.title,
  f.longitude,
  f.latitude,
  (3959 * cos(cos(radians('52.512452')) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) 
- radians('13.390931')) + sin(radians('52.512452')) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance
  FROM fitness_studio f
 WHERE (3959 * cos(cos(radians('52.512452')) * cos(radians(latitude)) *
        cos(radians(longitude) - radians('13.390931')) + 
        sin(radians('52.512452')) * sin(radians(latitude)))) < 1
 ORDER BY distance DESC
```

either to use a subquery:

```
WITH container AS (
SELECT
  f.title,
  f.longitude,
  f.latitude,
  (3959 * cos(cos(radians('52.512452')) * cos(radians(latitude)) *
   cos(radians(longitude) - radians('13.390931')) +
   sin(radians('52.512452')) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance
FROM fitness_studio f)
SELECT *
  FROM container
 WHERE distance < 1
 ORDER BY distance DESC
```

Please keep in mind that using such subquery may negatively affect execution plan and when your table is large enough execution speed becomes more important than query awkwardness.

PS: Note that ORDER BY may correctly get alias as parameter. Suppose it's cause ORDER BY doesn't affect selected rows, it just rotates them. Same picture with GROUP BY